# TypeError: 'NumPyMinimumEigensolver' object is not subscriptable

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I'm trying to implement the same Jupyter notebook Jin-Sung Kim gave in his YouTube video [The Variational Quantum Eigensolver — Programming on Quantum Computers — Coding with Qiskit S2E4](http://The%20Variational%20Quantum%20Eigensolver%20%E2%80%94%20Programming%20on%20Quantum%20Computers%20%E2%80%94%20Coding%20with%20Qiskit%20S2E4); however, I'm facing the error as below:

**Error:**

```
step 0
/Users/bambrozi/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibm-quantum-challenge-2020-ZWRg31rS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/core/hamiltonian.py:91: DeprecationWarning: The ChemistryOperator is deprecated as of Qiskit Aqua 0.8.0 and will be removed no earlier than 3 months after the release date. Instead, the FermionicTransformation can be used to transform QMolecules and construct ground state result objects.
  super().__init__()
/Users/bambrozi/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibm-quantum-challenge-2020-ZWRg31rS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/core/hamiltonian.py:415: DeprecationWarning: Processing a dictionary result is deprecated, pass a (minimum) eigensolver result now.
  warnings.warn('Processing a dictionary result is deprecated,'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-66becf9098c9> in <module>
     13     # exact classical result
     14     exact_result = NumPyMinimumEigensolver(qubit_op, aux_operators=aux_ops)
---> 15     exact_result = operator.process_algorithm_result(exact_result)
     16 
     17     # VQE

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibm-quantum-challenge-2020-ZWRg31rS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/core/chemistry_operator.py in process_algorithm_result(self, algo_result)
     88             return self._process_algorithm_result(algo_result)
     89         else:
---> 90             lines, result = self._process_algorithm_result(algo_result)
     91             result['algorithm_retvals'] = algo_result
     92             return lines, result

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibm-quantum-challenge-2020-ZWRg31rS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/core/hamiltonian.py in _process_algorithm_result(self, algo_result)
    374             # TODO return self._process_algorithm_result_excited_states(algo_result)
    375         else:
--> 376             return self._process_algorithm_result_deprecated(algo_result)
    377 
    378     def _process_algorithm_result_ground_state(self, algo_result: MinimumEigensolverResult) \

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/ibm-quantum-challenge-2020-ZWRg31rS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/core/hamiltonian.py in _process_algorithm_result_deprecated(self, algo_result)
    419 
    420         # Ground state energy
--> 421         egse = algo_result['energy'] + self._energy_shift + self._ph_energy_shift
    422         result['energy'] = egse
    423         lines = ['=== GROUND STATE ENERGY ===']

TypeError: 'NumPyMinimumEigensolver' object is not subscriptable
```

**Source-code:**

```
# %%
import numpy as np 
import pylab 
import copy
from qiskit import BasicAer 
from qiskit.aqua import aqua_globals, QuantumInstance
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import NumPyMinimumEigensolver, VQE 
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import SLSQP 
from qiskit.chemistry.components.initial_states import HartreeFock
from qiskit.chemistry.components.variational_forms import UCCSD
from qiskit.chemistry.drivers import PySCFDriver 
from qiskit.chemistry.core import Hamiltonian, QubitMappingType
# %%
molecule = 'H .0 .0 -{0}; Li .0 .0 {0}'
distances = np.arange(0.5, 4.25, 0.25)
vqe_energies = []
hf_energies = []
exact_energies = []
# %%
for i, d in enumerate(distances):
    print('step', i)

    # set up experiment:
    driver = PySCFDriver(molecule.format(d/2), basis='sto3g')
    qmolecule = driver.run()
    operator = Hamiltonian(qubit_mapping=QubitMappingType.PARITY,
                           two_qubit_reduction=True, 
                           freeze_core=True,
                           orbital_reduction=[-3, -2])
    qubit_op, aux_ops = operator.run(qmolecule)

    # exact classical result
    exact_result = NumPyMinimumEigensolver(qubit_op, aux_operators=aux_ops)
    exact_result = operator.process_algorithm_result(exact_result)

    # VQE
    optimzer = SLSQP(maxiter=1000)
    initial_state = HartreeFock(operator.molecule_info['num_orbitals'],
                                 operator.molecule_info['num_particles'],
                                 qubit_mapping=operator._qubit_mapping,
                                 two_qubit_reduction=operator._two_qubit_reduction)
    var_form = UCCSD(num_orbitals=operator.molecule_info['num_orbitals'],
                     num_particles=operator.molecule_info['num_particles'],
                     initial_state=initial_state,
                     qubit_mapping=operator._qubit_mapping,
                     two_qubit_reduction=operator._two_qubit_reduction)
    algo = VQE(qubit_op, var_form, optimzer, aux_operators=aux_ops)

    vqe_result = algo.run(QuantumInstance(BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')))
    vqe_result = operator.process_algorithm_result(vqe_result)

    exact_energies.append(exact_result.energy)
    vqe_energies.append(vqe_result.energy)
    hf_energies.append(vqe_result.hartree_fock_energy)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

`exact_result = NumPyMinimumEigensolver(qubit_op, aux_operators=aux_ops)`

should be

`exact_result = NumPyMinimumEigensolver(qubit_op, aux_operators=aux_ops).run()`

---

Here is the full code that I ran and its output:

```
# %%
import numpy as np 
import pylab 
import copy
from qiskit import BasicAer 
from qiskit.aqua import aqua_globals, QuantumInstance
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import NumPyMinimumEigensolver, VQE 
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import SLSQP 
from qiskit.chemistry.components.initial_states import HartreeFock
from qiskit.chemistry.components.variational_forms import UCCSD
from qiskit.chemistry.drivers import PySCFDriver 
from qiskit.chemistry.core import Hamiltonian, QubitMappingType
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg' # Makes the images look nice


molecule = 'H .0 .0 -{0}; Li .0 .0 {0}'
distances = np.arange(0.5, 4.25, 0.25)
vqe_energies = []
hf_energies = []
exact_energies = []
# %%
for i, d in enumerate(distances):
    print('step', i)

    # set up experiment:
    driver = PySCFDriver(molecule.format(d/2), basis='sto3g')
    qmolecule = driver.run()
    operator = Hamiltonian(qubit_mapping=QubitMappingType.PARITY,
                           two_qubit_reduction=True, 
                           freeze_core=True,
                           orbital_reduction=[-3, -2])
    qubit_op, aux_ops = operator.run(qmolecule)

    # exact classical result
    exact_result = NumPyMinimumEigensolver(qubit_op, aux_operators=aux_ops).run()
    exact_result = operator.process_algorithm_result(exact_result)

    # VQE
    optimzer = SLSQP(maxiter=1000)
    initial_state = HartreeFock(operator.molecule_info['num_orbitals'],
                                 operator.molecule_info['num_particles'],
                                 qubit_mapping=operator._qubit_mapping,
                                 two_qubit_reduction=operator._two_qubit_reduction)
    var_form = UCCSD(num_orbitals=operator.molecule_info['num_orbitals'],
                     num_particles=operator.molecule_info['num_particles'],
                     initial_state=initial_state,
                     qubit_mapping=operator._qubit_mapping,
                     two_qubit_reduction=operator._two_qubit_reduction)
    algo = VQE(qubit_op, var_form, optimzer, aux_operators=aux_ops)

    vqe_result = algo.run(QuantumInstance(BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')))
    vqe_result = operator.process_algorithm_result(vqe_result)

    exact_energies.append(exact_result.energy)
    vqe_energies.append(vqe_result.energy)
    hf_energies.append(vqe_result.hartree_fock_energy)
    
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(distances,vqe_energies, label ='Mean Values')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @kaj226 - thank you very much. In the end, I fixed it changing the same line you pointed out; however, calling the `.compute_minimum_eigenvalue()` instead of `.run()`. Here's the whole line: `exact_result = NumPyMinimumEigensolver(qubit_op, aux_operators=aux_ops).compute_minimum_eigenvalue()`. Jack Woehr was who helped me on this one via Qiskit Slack. Thank you both!